# why I dont get anything when I console log my draft RTK-QUERY?

Tags: react-native, expo, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I use rtk-query and want to add optimistic updates. The Problem is I didnt get any console log statement in "NotificationsApi.util.updateQueryData". After console.log('Start') nothing happens

```
export const NotificationsApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'NotificationsApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl: `${API_ENDPOINT}/`}),
  tagTypes: ['ALL'],
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    // All
    notificationsAll: build.query<INotificationsAllListData[], { user_id: number; }>({
      query: (data) => ({
        url: '/notifications',
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
      }),
      providesTags: ['ALL']
    }),
    removeNotificationById: build.mutation<void, Pick<INotificationsAllListData, 'type'> & { user_id: number; notification_id: number; }>({
      query: (data) => ({
        url: '/remove_notification',
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
      }),
      async onQueryStarted({ user_id, notification_id, type }, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
        console.log(notification_id);
        console.log('START');
        const patchResult = dispatch(
          NotificationsApi.util.updateQueryData('notificationsAll', undefined, (draft) => {
              console.log('DISPATCH');
          })
        )
        try {
          await queryFulfilled
          
        } catch {
          console.log('HI');
          patchResult.undo();
  

          /**
           * Alternatively, on failure you can invalidate the corresponding cache tags
           * to trigger a re-fetch:
           * dispatch(api.util.invalidateTags(['Post']))
           */
        }
      },
      invalidatesTags: ['ALL']
    }),
  })
});
```

I get successfull data when logging notifications_id, type and user_id but I didnt get the console.log statement "DISPATCH". when I also console log draft nothing happens I dont get any console log in there. Whats the problem ? I have also used optimstic updates in other files that works but not here.

Comment: are you trying to update the cache before the request becomes fulfilled?

Comment: based on https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/api-slice-utils#updatequerydata Note that the first two arguments (endpointName and args) are used to determine which existing cache entry to update. If no existing cache entry is found, the updateRecipe callback will not run.